# Why are the First Order's weapons designed this way?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, first-order

In [The Force Awakens](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/), the stormtroopers's weapons have a toyful black and white look. Does it serve an actual purpose or is it just fashionable ?

I think all armies consider black to be a standard issue for weapons.

Example:
[image: First order weapons]
<sub>(source: [figures.com](http://www.figures.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=305231&stc=1&d=1441301101))</sub>

Comment: Waiting for an ingenious answer to a...well...questionable question....

Comment: The Imperials are quite notorious for choosing aesthetics over functionality. That's a major reason why you've entire legions of white bucketheads on a forest moon. Quite evidently, someone in high ranking places likes this design theme...

Comment: Designing something destined for toys to look like a toy? The hell you say.

Comment: *Star Wars* takes place long, long ago in a galaxy far, far away. The Empire is under no obligation to follow the design principles of (some) armies on 20th and early 21st century Earth. In some historical eras, blue and orange striped jumpsuits were thought to be the last word in military style: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Group_of_swiss_guards_inside_saint_peter_dome.jpg

Comment: Let me know if you think I changed too much of this question but the tone certainly didn't note encourage people to answer.

Comment: What I'm wondering is why they're using left-handed guns if they're all right-handed.

Comment: White plastic parts show dirt better than black plastic parts -- that way, troop inspections have a better chance to find something to gig the privates for.

Answer (score 5):

The stormtroopers themselves aren't colored like real-world soldiers, they're black and white. The new black and white weapons at least now match their armor.

The filmmakers wanted *The Force Awakens* to feel new and updated but still stay firmly rooted in the familiar.

As Mark Hamill said in [an interview](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CTNJ51ghzdY),

> Nothing's changed really. I mean, everything's changed, but nothing's changed.

Other examples of familiar, yet slightly updated things:

- stormtroopers look very familiar
- their blasters look like they simply added a bit of white paint to them
- the new TIE fighters are old TIE fighters with the colors inverted
- C-3PO looks identical but has a red arm now
- etc.

It's just one if many ways the filmmakers tried to show us something familiar, but slightly new or updated.

Comment: In other words, they redid Episode IV with new faces and fancier CGI.

Comment: You didn't get that from your first viewing of the movie?